# Simple Question about the norm.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a Banach space $V$ with a norm $\|\cdot\|:V\to \mathbb{R}$. Is the following true for all linearly independent vectors $x,y\in V$?:
$$\|x+y\|\geq \|y\|,~~~~\|x+y\|\geq \|x\|$$

Comment: No, you can construct a simple counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Take, e.g. $y = -x$.

Comment: @LordSoth: those are not linearly independent.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Haha, that's right. I missed the condition in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $x=(1,0)$ and $y = (-1,0.1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note: To look for counter examples, suppose that $V$ is an inner-product space with inner-product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. In this case, $$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\langle x, y \rangle $$

So the inequalities you wrote are true if and only if both
$$
2 \langle x, y \rangle \geq -\|x\|^2~
\text{ and }
~2 \langle x, y \rangle \geq - \|y\|^2
$$
hold. Now, can you come up with some counterexamples which break one of these inequalities?

Comment: I don't think the space has an inner product. Can a space have a norm but no inner product?

Comment: @David Yes! There do exist normed spaces where the norms do not arise from an inner-product. There is a polarization identity that needs to be satisfied to ensure that a norm comes from an inner-product! Good point. However, *some* norms do come from an inner-product space (particularly Euclidean spaces with the standard dot product) which are good spaces to look for counter examples to your question. I've edited my answer to reflect your point.

Comment: I realize that now - yes - an inner-product space is still a Banach space

Comment: @David A Banach space in which the norm comes from an inner-product is called a Hilbert space. For example, most $L^1$ spaces are Banach spaces which are not Hilbert spaces, but $L^2$ spaces are Hilbert spaces.